# SonarQube analysis for different microservice solution using one sonarqube project

Tags: sonarqube, microservices, enterprise

I have 3 microservices (c#,dot net) all together required to aggregate the data from those services  and then show values in UI as required. I want to configure sonarqube in all these 3 microservices. I have a sonarqube project name "mysonarqube". In the yaml file of all microservices I have added this

```
-task: SonarQubePrepare@4
 inputs:
    SonarQube:'SonarQube Enterprise'
    scannermode:'MSbuild'
    projectKey: 'mysonarqube'
    projectName:'microservice1'
```

Project name replaced with microservice2, microservice3 respectively in each service solution.
After building 1st microservice I could see microservice1 analysis in sonarqube and then when building second microservice2 the first analysis for microservice1 got replaced with microservice2. Is this how it works?

Possible to have all the analysis in one project? How can I have all my solutions in one project? Or do I need to create separate SonarQube project for each microservice solution?

Answer (score 1):

The project is identified by its project key. If you use the same key for all analyses, they will overwrite each other. If you always build everything at the same time, you may build them all between *prepare* and *end* steps to have all the files gathered in one project. If you build/release separately, it would be wise to create and track separate SonarQube projects.